# Eclipse refactoring like "change method signature" for generic parameter lists?

Tags: java, eclipse, generics, types, refactoring

Is there an Eclipse refactoring equivalent to the "change method signature" refactoring that would allow you to modify the "signature" of a class, enum, or interfaces's generic parameters?

For instance, if I wanted to remove, reorder, or introduce additional generic parameters to a type, it would change the references to the type accordingly and add default values, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently there is no such refactoring, because the [enhancement request](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=372568) I entered has been assigned.